# signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, django, scrapy

i am new to django. I am trying to run my scrapy spider through django view. My scrapy code works perfectly when i run through command prompt. but when I try to run it on django it fails. 
The error message: signal only works in main thread.

my code in the django view(The following)

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import log, signals
from Working.spiders.workSpider import WorkSpider
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = WorkSpider(domain='scrapinghub.com')
crawler = CrawlerProcess(Settings())
crawler.start()
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

Please help me solve this. thank you

Comment: were you able to solve it. Could you please post your work around?

Comment: Same as the guy above. 

Comment: Having his same issue, but with pypetter

Comment: anyone? CrawlerRunner looks like lower level, I would prefer CrawlerProcess...?

Comment: `reactor.run(0)` will turn off signals

Answer (score 6):

the error basically say that you are not in a main thread so signal is not handled.

switching from CrawlerProcess to CrawlerRunner solved the problem for me ( i guess in CrawlerRunner you are in the main thread ) http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner

hope this helps you

Comment: is this not about in which thread your current programm is working?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to crawl without using signals

```py
def crawl(spider: Type[Spider], spider_kwargs: dict = None):
    spider_kwargs = {} if spider_kwargs is None else spider_kwargs
    crawler = CrawlerProcess()
    crawler.start()
    crawler.crawl(spider, **spider_kwargs)
    crawler.start(stop_after_crawl=True, install_signal_handlers=False)
```

Usage

```py
from scrapy import Spider

if __name__ == "__main__":

    class BaseSpider(Spider):
        name: str


    crawl(BaseSpider, { "name": "base_spider" })
```

Comment: Thanks @Alon Barad. This solves the issue however I've experienced that the `crawler.start()` right after `crawler = CrawlerProcess()` is unnecessary.